# Imiscible fluids for demonstration

Tags: solubility

I have been considering building a fluid dynamics demonstration.  Basically, it would be a thin plexiglass box, with some turbulence inducing elements attached to the back face, and a pump to move the fluid around.

Can anybody recommend a pair of fluids that will:

1. not mix/dissolve permanently
2. can be dyed different colors, while respecting (1)
3. won't react with plexiglas (or, alternatively, polycarbonate)
4. isn't toxic or particularly flammable
5. can be pumped with a "very" low power pump at temperatures suitable for humans (say, 60-100F)

The point of the demonstration is to create a "sustainable" chaotic system.  I might even point an HD camera at it, and extract random numbers from the video stream (maybe).

Answer (score 2):

[Have a look at this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/toc/jceda8/87/12)

Summarizing:

- put food coloring to 35% isopropyl alcohol in water.
- add ammonium sulfate

What happens ? Once ammonium sulfate added and the solution mixed, the ammonium sulfate dissolves, pushing the isopropyl alcohol out of the aqueous solution (and the food coloring as well).

A separate layer thus forms, that is clearly visible thanks to the food coloring.

The weak point of the whole story is that isopropyl alcohol is flammable...

*PS: I would have preferred to reply to @Michiel's answer and @Nicolau Saker Neto's comment: but I do not have enough reputation to do that...*

Answer (score 1):

You could use water and some low viscosity oil like olive oil or sunflower oil. Water can be dyed easily with food-coloring that you can buy at the local pharmacy or sometimes grocery store. Both substances are eatable and fairly inert (on the timescale of days at least).

Only a very small part of the oil will dissolve in the water and after saturation there is no problem any more. After thorough stirring the demixing process might be a bit slow since both oils have a density around 920 $\ce{kg/m^3}$ which is not that far from water, but you will have to try whether you can for example run the experiment by day and let the whole thing demix at night. If it doesn't properly demix you could consider going for a lower density oil.

Comment: Another way to possibly force quicker demixing is to increase the disparity between solvent polarities, which can be done easily enough by dissolving a highly polar substance in water, such as a salt. Sodium chloride is possibly the best idea, though it is slightly corrosive towards some metals. Sugar might work also, though it's less polar and would increase the viscosity of the water